# how to convert date 4/7/2011 12:00:00 AM to 7-Apr-2011?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have a datetime datatype field in mssql2005 database ...

which retrieves the date in gridview as .. 4/7/2011 12:00:00 AM

but i want it retrieve date as 7-Apr-2011

how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

If this is in a BoundField, try this:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="YourDateColumn" dataformatstring="{0:d-MMM-yyyy}" />
```

Comment: @Sumit why don't you accept this answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may also go this way;

String.Format("{0:d-MMM-yyyy}", DateTime.Now)

or even;

DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy");